# What is しきれてない in 理解しきれてない?

Tags: word-choice

I got the following sentence from manga 五等分の花嫁 (chapter 43 I believe), 俺はまだニ乃を理解しきれてないのかもしれない.

理解 is to understand and I'm thinking it's used with する here. It's verb stem is followed by きれてない. The closest thing I can think of is that 切れる is being used here but I'm not quite sure how that would make sense.

I think the sentence translates to something like. "I may still not understand Nino yet," but I could be wrong since I don't know what helper verb(?) this is.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15596/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56506/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33791/9831/ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66084/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V(ます stem) + 切る means to do to the end, to do/finish completely. 食べ切る = eat the whole meal / finish one's plate, etc.

From a quick google search: https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B-kiru/

切れる is the potential form of 切る.

俺はまだニ乃を理解しきれてないのかもしれない.  Maybe I still haven't been able to fully understand Nino yet.

Also related to your sentence, fyi: [Use of の with かもしれない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56095/use-of-%E3%81%AE-with-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

[Potential form vs Intransitive Verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36811/potential-form-vs-intransitive-verbs?rq=1)

Comment: `俺はまだニ乃を理解しきれてないのかもしれない. Maybe I still can't fully understand Nino yet.` How would it translate if it was ～し**きれない**のかもしれない instead of ～しきれて(い)ないのかもしれない ? ... (In other words, what's the て(いる) doing here?)

Comment: @Chocolate Is it not just the ~ている continuation of state?  "I am in the state of not being able to fully understand Nino"?  I'm only an intermediate, so if my answer is not fully correct I'd be happy to have the details filled in.

Comment: The ている is something like the perfect tense, "have done". 理解しきれていない "haven't fully understood" (lit. haven't been able to fully understand). This answer might be of help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42343/9831